# Create a custom emotions android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard but only with emotions. The keyboard is for the system not for my own application.

The problem: I cannot commit a text with the image. I try to send the text like a SpannableString but it not work.

I searched a lot but still don't have a answer. Someone can help me?

**Update**

I tried:

```
ImageSpan image = new ImageSpan(v.getContext(),R.drawable.ic_clock_active);
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(SMILE_ANCHOR);

spannable.setSpan(image, spannable.length() -
                         SMILE_ANCHOR.length(), spannable.length(), 0);

ic.commitText(spannable, 1);
```

Comment: SHow us what you've tried.  The correct (only) answer is an ImageSpan or custom Spannable